# Counting triangles

Tags: code-golf

You are required to find how many triangles are unique out of given triangles. For each triangle you are given three integers a,b,c , the sides of a triangle.

A triangle is said to be unique if there is no other triangle with same set of sides.

Note : It is always possible to form triangle with given sides.

**INPUT:**

First line contains n, the number of triangles. Each of next n lines contain three integers a,b,c (sides of a triangle).

**Output:**

print single integer, the number of unique triangles.

**Constraints:**

```
1 <= n <= 10^5
1 <= a,b,c <= 10^15
```

**Sample Input**

```
5
7 6 5
5 7 6
8 2 9
2 3 4
2 4 3
```

**Sample Ouput**

```
1
```

**Explanation**

```
only triangle with sides 8, 2, 9 is unique
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by no other triangle with the same set of sides. I think it would be helpful if you provided a few example input -> output pairs.

Comment: @ Gareth See the updated question

Comment: is the input of 1 triangle restricted to one line or can you ask for side a,b,c in turns? `side a: 1 -> side b: 3 -> side c: 5`

Comment: Why do you complicate the task by having first number telling you the number of lines? This unnecessarily complicates the programs in most languages. Can we just assume we have the triangles, without the count at the beginning?

Comment: Agree with Gareth. This challenge is not specified clearly.

Comment: This problem can be generalized to 'find the unique set in a list of sets'. I find code-golfing simple problems like these favors GolfScript or similar languages. Maybe to make it more interesting, there should be an option to provide clever solutions in more verbose languages, or a per language grouping scoring?

Comment: @Tomas - it doesn't say you have to *use* the information in the input; just that it is *there*...

Comment: @YiminRong - I've taken to doing these using the shortest code in the language *of my choice*.  I always read the answers with an implicit group-by-language in my head and I upvote the ones that I think are nice.  There's no point my trying to compete with any of the 'spewed-printer-garbage' languages; I can't read or verify them, and it is not worth my time to do so -- they could put `{sn£%^s#s}poop` and tell me it does the job and I wouldn't be any of the wiser  *(Or, "boo hoo, my language set is too verbose!" -- whichever works for you)*  ;-)

Comment: @jimbobmcgee '...it is not worth my time to do so...' - I disagree. I think it is worth every programmer's time to learn different types of language like array (APL, J, K etc.) or stack-oriented (GolfScript etc.) programming languages.

Comment: @Gareth - I think it's worth every programmer's time to learn *about* different types of language, as it can definitely help you in more abstract ways (such as, writing RPN expressions for RRDtool) but, if I turned up to work and started writing in GolfScript or APL, I'd be *required* to rewrite it at the next code review.  Besides, I'd probably need to rewrite it myself, *the next time I saw it*!

Comment: @Tomas having the first number is a standard in many code challenge communities, such as SPOJ, which afaik is the largest and most prolific such environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 22 characters

```
n%{~]$}%:^{]^\/,3<},,(
```

Includes the first line into the list of triangles but subtracts one from the result later. Run [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyI1CjcgNiA1CjUgNyA2CjggMiA5CjIgMyA0CjIgNCAzIgoKbiV7fl0kfSU6XntdXlwvLDM8fSwsKAo%3D&run=true).

*Commented code*

```
n%            # Split input into lines
{             # For each line
  ~]          # Evaluate the content and put into array
  $           # Sort the array (aka sides)
}%
:^            # Assign to variable ^
{             # Filter list of triangles
  ]           # Make array from triangle
  ^\/         # Count number of occurences in ^ by splitting
  ,3<         # and testing if number of parts is less than 3 (i.e. 
              # triangle occurse only once
},
,(            # Count distinct lines and subtract 1 (for first line)
```

Answer (score 3):

## k [22 chars]

```
{+/1=#:'={x@<x}'x:1_x}
```

#### Example

```
input:(5;7 6 5;5 7 6; 8 2 9;2 3 4;2 4 3)
input
5
7 6 5
5 7 6
8 2 9
2 3 4
2 4 3
```

Output

```
{+/1=#:'={x@<x}'x:1_x}[input]
1
```

#### Example

```
input:(3;1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9)
input
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Output

```
{+/1=#:'={x@<x}'x:1_x}[input]
3
```

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 18 chars/bytes*

```
{+/1=+/∘.(≡⍦)⍨1↓⍵}
```

Dialect is [Nars2000](http://www.nars2000.org/). Following the lead in the K answer, this code is a *function* that accepts a list of vectors, first the number of lines (which is ignored) and then the triangles. Let me know if this is not ok.

**Exploded view**

```
{             1↓⍵}   drop the first element of the list (the number of lines)
       ∘.(  )⍨       for each possible pair of vectors (triangles) from the list,
          ≡⍦         compare them as multisets: check whether they are the same triangle
     +/              sum each row: for each triangle, count how many others are the same
   1=                find out which ones are unique
 +/                  and count them
```

**Example**

```
      {+/1=+/∘.(≡⍦)⍨1↓⍵} 5(7 6 5)(5 7 6)(8 2 9)(2 3 4)(2 4 3)
1
      {+/1=+/∘.(≡⍦)⍨1↓⍵} 6(7 6 5)(5 7 6)(8 2 9)(2 3 4)(2 4 3)(2 4 6)
2
```

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
<sup>*: APL can be written in its own (legacy) single-byte charset that maps APL symbols to the upper 128 byte values. Therefore, for the purpose of scoring, a program of N chars *that only uses ASCII characters and APL symbols* can be considered to be N bytes long.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

### GolfScript (24 chars)

```
~](;3/{$}%:^1/{^\/,2=},,
```

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Oyc1CjcgNiA1CjUgNyA2CjggMiA5CjIgMyA0CjIgNCAzJwoKfl0oOzMveyR9JTpeMS97XlwvLDI9fSws)

This relies on the triangle sides being GolfScript literals of the same type (and hence sortable): it would [work equally well with strings](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Oyc1CiJnIiAiZiIgImUiCiJlIiAiZyIgImYiCiJoIiAiYiIgImkiCiJiIiAiYyIgImQiCiJiIiAiZCIgImMiJwoKfl0oOzMveyR9JTpeMS97XlwvLDI9fSws).

Comment: +1 for *almost* the same solution at *almost* the same time.

Answer (score 2):

### Bash and coreutils (<del>87</del>,<del>98</del>,<del>95</del>,93)

Assumes input file is called "f",

```
sed 1d f|while read n;do echo `echo $n |tr ' ' '\n'|sort|tr '\n' ' '`;done|sort|uniq -u|wc -l
```

Reads line by line, sorts each line separately, then sorts all the lines. Finally the unique lines are filtered and counted. Also works for strings.

EDIT: As [Yimin Rong](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15259/yimin-rong) pointed out, the first line containing the number of triangles is now handled (by removing it :) ).

Comment: I don't think it handles the first line correctly. I get 2 as the answer for the sample input with this script.

Comment: You're totally right. I missed the fact that there is a first line stating the number of triangles...

Comment: Cool, we came out with the same character counts but with completely different approaches!

Comment: I managed to shave 3 off by using "|" to pipe into the while loop instead of using "<" :)

Answer (score 2):

### C#: 250c

*(compiled to exe; assumes "line" means from stdin, so ran as `type trianglesfile | counttri.exe`)*

```
using System;using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(){int n=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());var a=new string[n];while(--n>=0)a[n]=string.Join(":",Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').OrderBy(x=>x));Console.Write(a.GroupBy(s=>s).Count(g=>g.Count()==1));}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());            // reads line from stdin; converts to int without validation
        var a = new string[n];

        while (--n >= 0) 
            a[n] = string.Join(":",                       // re-stringfy the following:
                               Console.ReadLine()         //  - read the next line
                                      .Split(' ')         //  - splits by space to form an array of sides
                                      .OrderBy(x => x)    //  - sorts by default comparison 
                   );

        Console.Write(
            a.GroupBy(s => s)                             // group on the sorted, stringified value
             .Count(g => g.Count() == 1)                  // count the number of groups which have 1 member
        );
    }
}
```

---

### C#: 116c

*(via LINQPad, in "C# Statements" mode; assumes "line" means any single line from an arbitrary string `s`, definition not counted)*

```
string s = @"5
1 2 3
2 1 3
4 5 6
3 1 2
8 7 6";            // <- input not included in overall count

Regex.Split(s,"\r\n").Skip(1).GroupBy(x=>string.Join(":",x.Split(' ').OrderBy(y=>y))).Count(g=>g.Count()==1).Dump();
```

Ungolfed:

```
string s = @"5
1 2 3
2 1 3
4 5 6
3 1 2
8 7 6";                                              // literal string definition, not counted

Regex.Split(s, "\r\n")                               // split on regex
     .Skip(1)                                        // who cares about the number of following lines?
     .GroupBy(x => string.Join(":",                  // re-stringify the following:
                               x.Split(' ')          //  - split by space into sides array
                                .OrderBy(y => y)))   //  - sort sides array
     .Count(g => g.Count() == 1)                     // count the number of groups that have 1 member
     .Dump();                                        // Output into LINQPad results pane
```

Answer (score 2):

### **Perl, <s>53</s> <s>50</s> 45**

```
perl -nE '$h{"@{[sort split]}"}++}{say-1+grep{!log}values%h'
```

Input either STDIN or append filename to the line above. "**50**" -- counting inside `' '` and `n`.

Another edit:

```
perl -nE '$h{1,sort split}++}{say-1+grep{!log}values%h'
```

i.e. **45**. As I understand, the trick here is to force list context when evaluating hash index. Then Perl joins this list with `$;` (cf. with `$"` in my previous take). Without `1,`, `sort` evaluates in scalar context = undefined behaviour.

Comment: The rules require you to count the cmdline flags you use other than `-e`/`-E`, so your total is 39.

Comment: Fixed, but managed to make it 38 ;)

Comment: Nice. Unfortunately, I just realized that this is solving a problem different than the one in the description. Your code is counting the number of triangles after omitting repeated triangles. But the description's test case makes it clear that the problem is to count the number of triangles that are not repeated at all. (For example, your program returns 3 instead of 1 for the given test case.)

Comment: You are certainly right. I updated my answer. Thanks a lot for checking and pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

### D - <del>201</del>, <del>172</del>, <del>171</del>, 170 chars

Reads from STDIN only and relies on D 2.x for UFCS (Uniform Function Call Syntax) and assumes the `-property` compiler flag isn't set.

```
import std.stdio,std.algorithm,std.conv;void main(){int n=[stdin.readln[0]].to!int;char[][]a;while(n-->0)a~=stdin.readln.dup.sort;a.group.filter!(x=>x[1]<2).count.write;}
```

Normal indented version:

```
import std.stdio, std.algorithm, std.conv;

void main()
{
    int n = [ stdin.readln[0] ].to!int;
    char[][] a;

    while( n --> 0 )
        a ~= stdin.readln.dup.sort;

    a.group.filter!( x => x[1] < 2 ).count.write;
}
```

Input:

```
F:\Code\Other>rdmd tri.d
5
7 6 5
5 7 6
8 2 9
2 3 4
2 4 3
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

## bash — 98 <del>113</del> characters

I'm sure this isn't the smallest `bash` solution (assumes `i` is the input file):

```
rm -f w;sed 1d i|while read L;do echo $L|xargs -n 1|sort|xargs -n 3 >>w;done;sort <w|uniq -u|wc -l
```

Explanation:

`rm -f w;` // delete working file

`sed 1d i|while read L;` // read each line, skipping the first one

`do echo $L|xargs -n 1|sort|xargs -n 3 >>w;` // normalize each line by sorting the elements

`done;` // end of while loop

`sort <w|uniq -u|wc -l` // sort all the lines, pull out unique ones and count

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell (116, 99 w/o import)

```
import Data.List
main=getContents>>=(\x->print((length.(filter((<2).length)).group.(map(sort.words)).tail.lines)x))
```

If the file `input` contains the example input, run with:

```
$ cat input | runghc solution.hs
1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 55 characters

```ruby
a=$<.map{|s|s.split.sort}
p a.count{|b|1==a.count(b)}-1
```

The code is pretty straightforward for golfing standards:

- first `a=$<.map{|s|s.split.sort}` reads all lineas from stdin, splits them into arrays, sorts them and stores them in the array `a`,
- then `a.count{|b|1==a.count(b)}` counts how many of those arrays appear only once in `a`,
- and the final `-1` is just not to count the first line read from stdin :)

Answer (score 1):

```c++
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

void unique_check();

typedef struct triangle
{
    int s1, s2, s3;

}t;

t *tp[10];

int no;
void main()
{
    int  i,ch=0;

    do
    {
        int ch;
        printf("Enter the no triangles\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &no);

        for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
        {
            tp[i] = (t *)malloc(sizeof(t));
            printf("Enter the sides of %d triangle ", i);
            scanf_s("%d", &tp[i]->s1);
            scanf_s("%d", &tp[i]->s2);
            scanf_s("%d" ,&tp[i]->s3);
        }

        unique_check();

        printf("Enter the choice\n1 Perform more \n2 End\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &ch);
        system("cls");


    } while (ch!=2);

}


void unique_check()
{
    int i, j, f = 0, count = 0,tri=0;

    for (i = 0; i < no; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < no; j++)
        {
            if (i == j)
                continue;
            else
            {
                if (((tp[i]->s1 == tp[j]->s1) || (tp[i]->s1 == tp[j]->s2) || (tp[i]->s1 == tp[j]->s3)) &&
                    ((tp[i]->s2 == tp[j]->s1) || (tp[i]->s2 == tp[j]->s2) || (tp[i]->s2 == tp[j]->s3)) &&
                    ((tp[i]->s3 == tp[j]->s1) || (tp[i]->s3 == tp[j]->s2) || (tp[i]->s3 == tp[j]->s3)))
                {
                    f = 0;
                    break;
                }

                else
                    f = 1;
            }

        }

        if (f == 1)
            tri++, f = 0;


    }

    printf("No of unique triangle\n%d\n",tri);



}
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! The question is a [tag:code-golf], so please try to use as few characters as possible, and include the language name and character count in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>12</s></sup> 8 bytes

```
#εkOmwt¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/nc1mz/3PKSQ9v@//9vymWuYKZgymWqAKS5LBSMFCy5jBSMFUyApImCMQA)

-4 bytes from Leo.

Comment: Nice job! I wouldn't have thought of using `k` to get unique lines easily. A couple of golfs for you: 1) `x' ` is exactly what `w` does 2) you could move the sort to be the function used by `k` instead of `I`, saving 2 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/nc1mz/3PKSQ9v@//9vymWuYKZgymWqAKS5LBSMFCy5jBSMFUyApImCMQA "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: @Leo cool. I'll add it in

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 17 bytes

This is not a serious participation, because Pyth is much younger than this question. Found the question while researching for another question and had to try it.

```
JmScd)t.zlfq/JT1J
```

Try it online: [Pyth Compiler/Executor](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lfqeT1.rSmScd)t.z&input=5%0A7%206%205%0A5%207%206%0A2%203%204%0A8%202%209%0A2%204%203&debug=0).

Wasted quite a few bytes on parsing the awkward input format.

```
       .z           read all of input
      t             discard the first line
 m                  map each line d to:
   cd)                 split d by spaces
  S                    and sort     
J                   store the result in J
          f     J   filter J for trianges T, which satisfy the condition:
            /JT        count T in J
           q   1        == 1
         l          length / number of remaining triangles, print
```

Another 17 byte solution, which uses the `.r` command (run length encoding).

```
lfqeT1.rSmScd)t.z
```